# Merging two lists from entity framework query results in 500 error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a query, which gets two lists, from two separate tables, however, when this gets called, I receive a 500 error in Swagger which says: `Can't process set operations after client evaluation, consider moving the operation before the last Select() call`

I'm not exactly sure how to resolve it.

```
public async Task<List<DtoForList>> GetData()
{
  var dataSet1 = from abc in dbContext.ABCs
                 join def in dbContext.DEF on abc.Id equals def.abcId
                 where def.Name == "Bob"
                 select new DtoForList
                 {
                    // some stuff
                 };
 
   var dataSet2 = from ghi in dbContext.GHI
                 join jklmn in dbContext.JKLMN on ghi.Id equals jklmn .ghiId
                 where jklmn.Name == "Bob"
                 select new DtoForList
                 {
                    // some stuff
                 };

   return dataSet1.Concat(dataSet2).OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn).ToList();
}
```

Basically there are four tables. Two major tables, with two lookup tables tied to them. I get all that data and format it into the same object structure (`DtoForList`), then I need to merge those two lists and return them to the controller/service. Yet this throws an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `var dataSet = await (from ...).ToListAsync();`?

Comment: I still receive Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.

Comment: To debug: Can you do: `dataSet1.ToList()`, Can you do the same with dataSet2?  Are they equal type? and what happens after `dataSet1.OrderBy(x => ...).ToList()`?  And dataSet2? Can you do `dataSet1.Concat(dataSet2).ToList()`? Where in all these tests do you get your error?

Answer (score 0):

There is a know issue [Set operations: support when placed after client evaluation in projection](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16243) you can try by re-writing the query so that the Union operation occurs before client evaluation does

```
// pseudo code
var dataSet1 = from abc in dbContext.ABCs
                 join def in dbContext.DEF on abc.Id equals def.abcId
                 where def.Name == "Bob";
 
var dataSet2 = from ghi in dbContext.GHI
                 join jklmn in dbContext.JKLMN on ghi.Id equals jklmn .ghiId
                 where jklmn.Name == "Bob";
                 
dataSet1.Concat(dataSet2).select(x=> new DtoForList() ).OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn).ToList();
```